# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**THE SITUATION:**

I am trying to make a very simple login form in my Ionic 2 app.

No matter what I try, I keep getting this error:

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

[image: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.]

**THE CODE:**

**The page component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder }  from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: 'login-page.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

    loginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() 
    {
        console.log('Login page loaded');

        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    submitLogin() 
    {
        console.log('Doing login..');
    }

}
```

**The view:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>LoginPage</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submitLogin()">

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input #email type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input #password type="text" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

</ion-content>
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Do you why am I getting the error?

Do you know what is wrong with that code?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the code in the `ionViewDidLoad` into the constructor. It's probably not assigning the form in time, causing the view to use undefined

Comment: Oh my God thanks! It was just that! You can write it as an answer and I can mark it as correct!!

Comment: I added it in ngOnInit and it works. Think the code is better that way. Its unfortunate that  ionic doesnt have alifecycle called ``ionWillLoad``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the code in the `ionViewDidLoad` into the constructor. It's probably not assigning the form in time, causing the view to use undefined

Answer (score 1):

The formBuilder init was ngOnInit method. That must be in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

declare the form builder inside the constructor

```
constructor()
{
 this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });
}
```

this solved my problem.